# Can Reactor 3.0.x be used with Spring4.3.x version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, reactive-programming

I am new to reactor and trying to use Reactor 3.0.x with Spring 4.3.x version.
Reactor 3.0 is the latest version available with many architectural reforms over Reactor 2.0.
Could anyone please tell me if it is possible to use it with Spring 4.3.x?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Reactor only [prerequisite](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#prerequisites) is Java 8 and above.

Reactor initiative was merged in Spring 5 and is now used from some of the Spring's 5 core APIs. So naturally there's reactive support out-of-the box in Spring 5 like reactive support for web endpoints, reactive web client, reactive serialization and deserialization to and from JSON (Jackson) and XML (JAXB). Check out the release notes for complete info.

This does not stop you in any way to use Reactive in a Spring 4.x project. You just don't have some of those Spring's features having the reactive support, but you can freely use Java 8 streams, core Mono/Flux and async drivers to achieve reactive behavior in your project.

Comment: Thanks Hovanessyan. I tried using EventBus in my application but it seem this class is deprecated from Reactor 3 onwards and ReplayProcessor class is used in favour of EventBus. I could not get any working example to understand how ReplayProcessor  class works. Please provide some code snippet or any reference link to use this class.